Combine Python f-string with printf style formatting?
I need to format a command line where some parameters come from simple variables, and others are the result of a longer expression. Python f-strings work well for the variables, and I'm using a printf-style %s and providing the long expression outside the string because it would just clutter the command template too much if placed inline:
run(f"""zstd -dc {diff_file} | 
      git apply -p2 {exclude_args} --directory='%s'""" % (os.getcwd() + "/output"))

I didn't store the directory parameter in a named variable because it only gets used once as opposed to diff_file and exclude_args.
Is there a cleaner way to avoid putting os.getcwd() + "/output" directly in the f-string, and also avoid mixing old printf %s syntax and new f-strings ?
Are there downsides to doing it like above other than it being a bit confusing to someone who reads the code ?
Edit: to clarify, my question is how to put placeholders in f-strings without declaring additional named variables, not how to inline calls to getcwd() in f-strings.

No need to store it, just use it as {os.getcwd()}

Do you actually need an absolute path explicitly constructed from the current working directory, rather than just using "output" by itself?

What does your "cluttered if placed inline" version look like?

@nocomment: Something like what has been suggested in the answers: run(f"git apply -d '{(os.getcwd()}/output}' -p2").

Don't use string formatting at all.
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, run

p = Popen(["zstd", "-dc", diff_file], stdout=PIPE)

# exclude_args itself should be a list like ["foo", "bar"] rather than
# a single string like "foo bar"
run(["git", "apply", "-p2", *exclude_args, "--directory", Path.cwd() / "output"], stdin=p.stdout)

Instead of creating a shell pipeline, create one subprocess for the zstd command, then connect its standard output to the standard input of a separate git subprocess.
You probably don't need Path at all; "output" alone as a relative path can be used by git as long as you don't execute git with a working directory different from your Python script's working directory.

From the docs

Formatted string literals (also called f-strings for short) let you include the value of Python expressions inside a string by prefixing the string with f or F and writing expressions as {expression}.

So
run(f"""zstd -dc {diff_file} | 
      git apply -p2 {exclude_args} --directory='{os.getcwd()}/output'""")


A line continuation must be added If the new line after the pipe is needed
run(f"""zstd -dc {diff_file} | \
      git apply -p2 {exclude_args} --directory='{os.getcwd()}/output'""")


